# Запуск приложения через ссылку в браузере

Tags: веб-программирование, visual-studio, github

На GitHub есть возможность скачать репозиторий, также есть возможность открыть проект в Visual Studio.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку всплывает сообщение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код кнопки "Open in Visual Studio".

```
<a class="btn btn-outline get-repo-btn tooltipped tooltipped-s tooltipped-multiline js-get-repo" data-hydro-click="{&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;clone_or_download.click&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:{&quot;feature_clicked&quot;:&quot;OPEN_IN_VISUAL_STUDIO&quot;,&quot;git_repository_type&quot;:&quot;REPOSITORY&quot;,&quot;repository_id&quot;:51754485,&quot;client_id&quot;:&quot;1077169340.1543886840&quot;,&quot;originating_request_id&quot;:&quot;0761:262E7:7D7D088:C0AA794:5D8358C2&quot;,&quot;originating_url&quot;:&quot;https://github.com/mezox/PhotoEditor&quot;,&quot;referrer&quot;:null,&quot;user_id&quot;:41971300}}" data-hydro-click-hmac="1b6515f06e9db9bc93998b638c346246d2c565f9e9a3721346e904552bca42d6" data-open-app="visual-studio" aria-label="Clone mezox/PhotoEditor to your computer and open it in Visual Studio." href="git-client://clone?repo=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmezox%2FPhotoEditor">Open in Visual Studio</a>
```

Вопрос в том как мне можно реализовать подобное? Чтобы со своего сайта открыть клиент?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта

1) Сделать так, чтобы установщик клиента записывал некоторые значения в реестр

2) Вручную изменить реестр с нужным названием

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myprogram]
@="URL:myprogram Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myprogram\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myprogram\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myprogram\shell\open\ command]
@="\"C:\\myprogram\" \"%1\""
```